# Set dynamic validation criteria on HTML elements based on predefined configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got an employee html form with several input tags.
[image: Employee data screen]
the problem is some input tags had dynamic validation criteria based on current user logged to the system.
for example:
user 1 : consider ssn as mandatory field with 14 character
user 2 : consider ssn as mandatory field with 10 character.

I get the criteria from DB.
I succeeded to implement `required` like this:

```
   var screenConfig = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewBag.ScreenConfig));
   $(document).ready(function () {
    _.each(screenConfig, function(value, key) {
            if (value.IsRequired == true) {
                $("#"+value.ElementId).attr("required", "required");
                $("#"+value.ElementId).addClass("required-input");
            }


    });});
```

But I got stuck with text input length, I can't think of something other than sending script from server to handle each element separately.
Can it be done other way efficiently??

Comment: I think you're looking for the HTML input attribute [`maxlength`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)?

Comment: @Gareth `maxLength` will limit the max,OK, but what I need is to force a specific length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Avitus Suggestion:
That's what I made to make dynamic validation on HTML elements based on predefined configuration:
1. I created two tables in DB ScreenElement, ScreenSettings:

```
    CREATE TABLE [HR].[ScreenElement](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ElementId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ElementName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ScreenId] [int] NULL,
    [IsRequired] [bit] NULL,
    [MinLength] [int] NULL,
    [MaxLength] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ScreenElement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [HR].[ScreenSettings](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NameA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NameL] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ScreenKey] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ScreenSettings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

2.I get configuration by screen keyword that's `ControllerName.ActionName` and pass it in a ViewBag when the screen loads I serialize it to js object.
3.When document ready.I mark the elements with `data-x` attributes and some styling classes.

```
var screenConfig = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewBag.ScreenConfig));


$(document).ready(function () {
    _.each(screenConfig, function(value, key) {
            if (value.IsRequired == true) {
                $("#"+value.ElementId).attr("required", "required");
                $("#"+value.ElementId).addClass("required-input");
            }
            if (value.MinLength !== 0 && value.MaxLength !== 0&&value.MaxLength>=value.MinLength) {
                $("#"+value.ElementId).attr("data-min", value.MinLength.toString());
                $("#"+value.ElementId).attr("data-max", value.MaxLength.toString());
                if (value.MinLength === value.MaxLength) {
                    $("#"+value.ElementId).attr("data-length", value.MinLength.toString());
                }

            }


    });});
```

That's It.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is add an additional attribute to the input tag specifying the length.  Then on form submit do a .each for the inputs that have the additional attribute.  Then in that .each validate the length.